# Show section of an address in GDB

Tags: debugging, gdb

I wanted to know how can GDB automatically tell you that an address falls into a section.
I know that to see sections you type `maintenance info sections`, however its a bit tedious to look into each address and manually check if they fall in section `x` or `y`.
Is there a command that does that for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can GDB automatically tell you that an address falls into a section.

Isn't that exactly what `info symbol $addr` does?

```
int x;
int y = 42;
const int z = 24;

int main() {
  return x + y + z;
}

gcc -g t.c && gdb -q ./a.out

(gdb) info sym &x
x in section .bss
(gdb) info sym &y
y in section .data
(gdb) info sym &z
z in section .rodata
(gdb) info sym &main
main in section .text
```